# Para o movimento de um picturebox c# windows

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um picturebox e faço o movimento dele apenas para a direita e esquerda, mas gostaria de que quando o final da imagem chegar na borda do form e o inicio, não fosse mais possível movimentar ela.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta desta forma:

Gostaria que ficasse desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o scrpit utilizado:

```
    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            x = e.X;                
        }
    }

    private void imagemPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {             
            imagemPictureBox.Left += (e.X - x);                                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Somente com estas linhas de código é meio difícil de deduzir, mais acredito que você tem que testar o Width do formulário antes de realizar a movimentação do PictureBox

```
private void imagemPictureBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
    {
          x = e.X;                
    }
}

private void imagemPictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {             
        if (x > 0 && x < this.Width)
           imagemPictureBox.Left += (e.X - x);                                
    }
}
```

Comment: Vou analisar e tentar algumas pesquisas.